# Convert varchar to int

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am having 20 lacs rows in a table, and one column in that table is of type `varchar`, and I need to change in to be a column of type `decimal (18,2)` because in the database column value are decimal and I need to change all column, please help me out.

Comment: Maybe you should investigate what rows are not matching decimals and include those in your question. Seems like people are solving your problem with correct code but you have not given all the parameters required to solve your real problem.

Comment: You obviously have data in your column that is **not** numeric - find it using `SELECT (cols) FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE ISNUMERIC(yourcolumn) = 0`; clean up that data, and **then** try again...

Answer (score 2):

Why not

```
CAST(COLUMN AS DECIMAL(18,2))
```

or maybe a [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

You may want to also use [`ISNUMERIC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) to make sure it is convertible

Comment: @ManojWadhwani: well in that case you must have some data that is **not** really an `int` in your `varchar` column. Filter that out first, remove or correct those rows - then try again

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer to show how to look for values that are valid to cast. ISNUMERIC(COLUMN) = 1 tells you numeric values, ISNUMERIC(COLUMN) <> 1 tells you the invalid ones. As @marc_s said, you will need to remove or correct the non-numeric rows or nothing will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try Convert

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Something like this

```
alter table sqlTable add newColumn

UPdate sqlTable
Set newColumn = convert(decimal(18,2),oldcolumn)

alter table sqlTable drop oldcolumn
```

Comment: Same Error :Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Answer (score 0):

To migrate the data - if indeed that is your requirement - you're probably best off adding a new column to the table, doing an update into that column, checking the data and then dropping the old column.  If you want to keep the original column name you could repeat the process.

So
1. `alter table mytable add myNewColumn int` (or decimal(18,2) depending on your requirement)
2. update mytable set myNewColumn = `cast(myOldColumn as int) or convert(int, myOldColumn)` - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx
3. visually check data
4. `alter table mytable drop myOldColumn`

Comment: Tried but getting same error :alter table TestData
alter column [NET_ACCOUNTED] [decimal](18, 2) NULL

Comment: I'm not suggesting you alter a column - instead that you add a new column of the required data type and get data into it.  As per other feedback - you need to check that data is recognised as being numeric using ISNUMERIC.  If you're having issues with particular rows, what data is failing to convert?